# Disable lint for dependencies

Tags: java, android, lint

I'm trying to setup lint check for my Android project. I've started with simply running

```
lint myProject --html report.html
```

to generate the report file.

I've found out that in this report file there're warnings present which are not related to my project but to the .aars which my project depends on. For example:

> build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.facebook.android\facebook-android-sdk\3.22.0\res\layout\com_facebook_picker_image.xml:18: [Accessibility] Missing contentDescription attribute on image

The issue is within Facebook library. I can't do anything about it, so how can I disable lint checks for dependencies?

Comment: [Android Lint report for my project only, excluding library projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9822019/android-lint-report-for-my-project-only-excluding-library-projects)